# Why do I get glitchy graphics when drawing scene with scene2D?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to display a simple text for a menu UI using scene2D, but for some reason nothing is being displayed here. The screen displays pure black.

```
public class ScreenMenu implements Screen {

MyGame myGame;
SpriteBatch batch;
Stage stage;
Label labelNewGame, labelContinue, labelCredits;

public ScreenMenu(MyGame myGame) {
    this.myGame = myGame;
}

@Override
public void show() {
    init();
    BitmapFont font = initFont();
    initLabels(font);
    initStage();
}

private void init() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}

private BitmapFont initFont() {
    return new FontLoader().getMichroma();
}

private void initLabels(BitmapFont font) {
    Label.LabelStyle labelStyle = new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE);
    labelNewGame = new Label("New Game", labelStyle);
    labelContinue = new Label("Continue", labelStyle);
    labelCredits = new Label("Credits", labelStyle);
}

private void initStage() {
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    stage.addActor(labelNewGame);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    GlHelper.clearScreen();
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    myGame.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
}
}
```

The following class contains the `clearScreen` function. If I don't run it, the entire screen becomes super glitchy, **but** I can see the [New Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtDDE.png) text.

```
public class GlHelper {

public static void clearScreen() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

public static void clearScreen(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(red, green, blue, alpha);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *becomes super glitchy"?
How is the `ScreenMenu` class being initialized and used, you're not initializing it more than once are you?
If you change the implementation of `initFont` to just `return new BitmapFont();`, does the problem persist?

Comment: @bornander The screenshot is linked in the same sentence. I tried returning `new BitmapFont()' and the text appears! Is it a problem with the font I used? (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/michroma)

Comment: @bornander Okay, I feel stupid now. In the `FontLoader` implementation I set the `FreeTypeFontParameter` `color` to black. Apparently it overrides the `Color.WHITE` argument from `LabelStyle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `FontLoader` implementation I set the `FreeTypeFontParameter` color to black. Apparently it overrides the `Color.WHITE` argument from `LabelStyle`.